# Prove if set of P4 is linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra

Hi I'm trying to prove if this set is linearly independent

$s=1-x^4,1+x+x^3+x^4,1+x-x^3+x^4,1-x^2$

I need to prove

$c1(1-x^4)+c2(1+x+x^3+x^4)+c3(1+x-x^3+x^4)+c4(1-x^2)=0$

So I've rearranged the equation as

$x^4(-c1+c2+c3)+x^3(c2-c3)+x^2(-c4)+x(c2+c3)+(c1+c2+c3+c4)=0$

Then:

$-c1+c2+c3=0$

$c2-c3=0$

$-c4=0$

$c2+c3=0$

$c1+c2+c3+c4=0$

After this step how can I prove c1=c2=c3=c4=0 since my system is overdetermined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are left with the following system of equations: $$\left\{\begin{array}{llll}-c_1+c_2+c_3=0\\c_2-c_3=0\\-c_4=0\\c_2+c_3=0\\c_1+c_2+c_3+c_4=0.\end{array}\right.$$
By the third line, you know $c_4=0$.

Making the difference of the first line by the forth line, you know $-c_1=0$, so that $c_1=0$.

Summing up the second line with the forth line, you know $2c_2=0$, so that $c_2=0.$

Reinjecting all these informations in the fifth line, you get: $c_3=0$.

This is one way to do it.

Answer (score 3):

Form a matrix:$$\left[\begin{array}{cccc|c}-1&1&1&0&0\\0&1&-1&0&0\\0&0&0&-1&0\\0&1&1&0&0\\1&1&1&1&0\end{array}\right]$$
Rearrange and do row reductions:$$\left[\begin{array}{cccc|c}1&1&1&1&0\\0&1&0&0&0\\0&0&1&0&0\\0&0&0&1&0\\0&2&2&1&0\\\end{array}\right]$$
From Row $2,3,4$, Now that it's obvious $c_2=c_3=c_4=c_1=0$